# Retrieve all keywords present in a Bugzilla instance through webservice

Tags: web-services, xml-rpc, bugzilla

I have to get all the keywords present in bugzilla installation via webservice. I have installation 3.6 Can I know what is the method to get the same and the sample xml to retrieve the same. I am using XMLRPC and have bugzilla version 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Bugzilla::Webservice::Bug is the place to start. Use the get method to retrieve the bug then inspect the summary field.

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html#Bug_Information